# What's wrong with my insert statement?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ms-access

I am receiving a SYNTAX error in Visual Studio. Using Access DB

```
INSERT INTO Order (oProduct, oQty, oPrice) 
SELECT pName, pQty, pPrice
FROM Product 
WHERE pName = 'Big Mac'";
```

Table: Product
Fields: pName, pPrice, pQty

Table: Order
Fields: oProduct, oQty, oPrice

Comment: there seems to be a trailing " there, typo?

Comment: You have a `"` in the end of the query. And if this was for SQL Server you would have to put order table in brackets `[Order]`. Don't know if order is a reserved word in access or not, probably is.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: **If** this was for SQL Server then they could use standard SQL quoted identifiers, being double quotes, so your "have to" assertion would not be correct. For MS Access, the quoted identifiers are square brackets only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Order" is a reserved word in SQL.  Escape it with square brackets, like:

```
 insert into [Order]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra " at the end of your query.

Answer (score 1):

Either place `Order` table in double quotes, or there is excessive double quotes at the end of your line, just before semicolon.